# VBA pass the range of a sub to another sub

Tags: vba, subroutine

I want to pass the range : Set cell = bd.Range(FoundColumn & StartRow & ":" & FoundColumn & LastRow) of the Sub FoundVisit() to another Sub SumVisit() and then sum all visits.

- Sub FoundVisit() : find the column where the header is equal to visits and set the range.
- Sub SumVisit() : sum the range found of the Sub FoundVisit().

---

```
Sub FoundVisit(StartRow As Long, LastRow As Long, FoundColumn As String, StringToFind As String, ResultRange As Range, cell As Range)

    Dim bd As Worksheet: Set bd = Sheets("BDD")
    Dim rf As Worksheet: Set rf = Sheets("REF")

    StringToFind = rf.Range("D2").Value

    Set ResultRange = bd.Cells.Find(What:=StringToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

    If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing"
    Else
        'Get the row after the header
        StartRow = ResultRange.Row + 1
        'Column of the header
        FoundColumn = Split(Cells(, ResultRange.Column).Address, "$")(1)
        'Last row under that header
        LastRow = bd.Range(FoundColumn & bd.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'The range that I need
        Set cell = bd.Range(FoundColumn & StartRow & ":" & FoundColumn & LastRow)

    End If

End Sub

Sub SumVisit()

    With Sheets("SUMMARY")

    Sheets("SUMMARY").Label1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(FoundVisit)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a range argument to the sub, so something like `set r=range("a1:a100")` then a sub like `MySub(rng as excel.range)` then call like `MySub(r)`  or declare the range at procedure level, or public.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @SJR  The Sub FoundVisit() search fo the range where the header is (Visits), if exist then set the range. In the Sub SumVisit() I want to sum the range set in Sub FoundVisit().

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand how functions work. `FoundVisit` has several arguments, e.g. `StartRow` but you are then defining the same variable in the code. Also your function doesn't actually return anything.